# Настройка и использование Tomcat

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

Как  лучше поставить Tomcat на убунту: через apt-get или же использовать скачанный?

Каким образом настроить хосты и подключить к Intellij?

Нужно также поменять порт,  делаю так в server.xml, но никакой реакции, по-прежнему запускается на 8080:

```
 <Connector port="8181" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
               redirectPort="8443" />
```

Подключил сервер, но при запуске говорит, что порт занят, 
 и какой бы не поставил - картина та же.

Comment: http://devcolibri.com/4249

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Мы всегда используем скачанный вручную Tomcat, потому что это дает большую гибкость. В бинарных дистрибутивах линукса (в противовес source-based типа Gentoo) весьма непросто иметь несколько разных версий одного и того же софта, поэтому отвязанный от пакетного менеджера Томкат освобождает руки: можно иметь сколько угодно его версий, просто копируя директории. Кроме того, это позволяет работать не используя аккаунт root вообще.

Чтобы подключить Tomcat к IntelliJ IDEA, нужно создать новую run/debug configuration, выбрать из списка шаблонов Tomcat -> Local и указать путь к директории, куда распакован Tomcat. Потом на вкладке deployment нужно выбрать артефакт, и это всё. При запуске этой конфигурации, Идея сама правильно развернет приложение на Томкате.

Для того, чтобы поменять порт, нужно поменять connector port именно так, как написано в вопросе:

```
<Connector port="9090" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

Это всё, что нужно сделать. Если он всё еще не может заблокировать порт, значит проблема в настройках вашей системы (Ubuntu), а не в самом Томкате и его конфигурации. Можно, например, попробовать убить все процессы java: `sudo killall java`, возможно вам мешает один из ранее запущенных Томкатов.

Учтите, что если вы меняете порт на один из привелигированных портов (< 1024), на Ubuntu/Debian нужно сделать дополнительные действия:

Для Томката, установленного через пакетный менеджер:

- `sudo apt-get install authbind`
- `sudo vim /etc/default/tomcat7` - включить в нем опцию `AUTHBIND=yes`

(По идее, этого должно хватить, если нет - читаем дальше)

Для установленного вручную Томката:

- `sudo apt-get install authbind`
- Сделать порт 80 (или куда вы хотите соединяться) доступным для authbind:

  `touch /etc/authbind/byport/80`

  `chmod 500 /etc/authbind/byport/80`

  `chown tomcat7 /etc/authbind/byport/80`

  (здесь tomcat7 - это любой пользователь, от которого будет работать ваш томкат)
- Включить IPv4 по умолчанию (authbind пока не умеет хорошо работать с IPv4). Для этого в каталоге с Томкатом нужно отредактировать файл `bin/setenv.sh`, добавив туда строчку:

  `CATALINA_OPTS="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"`
- В директории с томкатом, в файле `bin/startup.sh`, поменять строчку типа

  `exec "$PRGDIR"/"$EXECUTABLE" start "$@"`

  на

  `exec authbind --deep "$PRGDIR"/"$EXECUTABLE" start "$@"`

Если вы так и не сможете победить настройку порта, можно переназначить его на нужный с помощью iptables:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
sudo iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -p tcp -d 127.0.0.1 --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
```

После этого Томкат будет доступен сразу по двум портам: и по 80, и по 8080.

(Понятно, что совершенно полная инструкция по настройке редиректа портов выглядит намного длиннее, и это выходит за рамки данной темы. В случае проблем с редиректом портов, лучше создавать новые вопросы.)

Comment: а как настроить переменную окружения ?

Comment: добавьте ее в /etc/profile и перезагрузите компьютер (это будет общесистемная переменная), или в ~/.bashrc (или в ~/.zshrc если у вас OSX и oh-my-zsh) - это будет для текущего пользователя. Написать нужно нечто вроде export VAR_NAME=VAR_VALUE (перед и после знака = не должно быть пробелов, это важно)

Comment: VAR_HOME - CATALINA_HOME. А VAR_VALUE , должен быть путь к какому-то файлу ?

Comment: CATALINA_HOME - это путь до директории, куда вы установили Томкат